# My role has changed to developing reports about my department, am I doing a different job?

Tags: job-description, title

I started working at a IT/Helpdesk position at my company about a year ago. Since then my responsibilities have really escalated from that of a normal helpdesk agent at the company.

I spend about 60% of my time at work, working in excel, to produce numbers and graphs and statistics for various things upper management is interested in.

I also create various weekly reports about employee performance/department stats. The goal with these reports is to eventually have the "template" be taken to our development team and be incorporated into our reporting system (CUIC)

I know soon they want me to start learning how to incorporate access Databases and eventually SQL databases since a lot of the reports I'm creating are really starting to take some more advanced logic and larger sets of data.

While I know my current job title is just Technical Support Agent, but what is this job I'm actually doing? Is there a name for it and does it sound similar to other fields? I really want to get a grasp on what I'm worth for doing this work and how doing similar work pays in the industry but I just can't pinpoint a name on it. Currently there is only 1 other person in the company that does similar work and he is in control of our phone systems as his more primary role. While he gives me some tips/tricks I do most of this work on my own.

Comment: I'd probably suggest 'System Administrator' as another title. However, Technical Support Agent is pretty ambiguous but accurate.

Comment: Data analyst might be accurate.

Comment: If you're looking at putting this on a CV, I'd put this down as the actual job title, then cover that this role has developed into more of a BI role as per TolMera's answer

Comment: Technical Support Agent sounds about right to me. I disagree with the BI Data Analyst answers, except if what you're doing involves fairly complex analyses where you actually have to extract the business value and not just follow rules that were provided to you by management. Sounds like you do a bit of everything, so Tech Support sounds right to me (if not so glamorous).

Answer (score 4):

You are performing the duties of a Business Intelligence (BI) Analyst.

[You can have a look at this BI description from MIT](https://ist.mit.edu/sites/default/files/about/org/roles/BI_Analyst_Position_Description_v4.pdf)

[Or the much shorter and simpler description here](http://www.snagajob.com/job-descriptions/business-intelligence-analyst/)

Answer (score 0):

Your job is whatever is listed on your job description as held by your HR department.

If that differs significantly from your current on-going tasks, then I'd think you're in a position to negotiate a raise and change of job title.

If that doesn't pan out, you're in a great position to find another vacancy that equates to your newly-found skills and offers the appropriate remuneration.

Answer (score 0):

Clearly, this is Data Analyst position, as TolMera stated out. Also called BI Analyst. Thing is, these guys are way better paid than common IT/Helpdesk people (if compared with identical experience level). For me personally, it looks like they hired you under a completely false job title in order to pay you less. You should talk about this with your boss and the HR.

Comment: You are perhaps assuming pre-planned malice when reactive problem solving adequately explains the OP's change in role. I'd agree that the OP could do well to ask about the changes, and maybe about the role becoming more highly skilled and valuable, but I'd advise not to immediately assume some kind of pre-planned bait-and-switch tactic.

Comment: All job contracts do include, explicitly or implicitly, "other duties as assigned".

Comment: I would agree with both Acroneos and Neil, BI is much better paid, with certs behind them. You show the skill for this, and I can see your employer taking advantage and moving you to a new position (without reassigning you, and avoiding a pay increase). As Keshlam said your contract will probably include "Other Duties from time to time"  However 60% of your week on "other duties" really does constitute a change of role, bring it up with HR. You're obviously long term, and have been doing the new job long term, so could/should renegotiate your contract, not just your pay, your entire contract.